# Match 2 tables - then insert or modify to new table

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, comparison

I'm trying to find matches within two tables. first I'll compare the phone number then the last name etc. I'll insert the matches in a new table.

My question is first if it'll be faster and better if I do it directly in SQLServer or  in my .net program?

If SQL is better I need some help;

I want to check if that record exist in the match table, if it does it should only modify this record t specify that there's an other match.

I could do a separate insert and modify query for each type of match. I just wonder if there's a nicer way of doing it.

I tried the merge, it worked to insert but on modify it gives me an error, please see below.

```
MERGE Matches AS M
USING (SELECT DOE.REG, sl.id FROM DOE INNER JOIN SL ON DOE.TEL = sl.phone) AS DOE
On M.doeid = DOE.reg
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET m.Phonematch = 1, datemodified = getdate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(DoeID, SatmarID, PhoneMatch , Verified, DateCreated)
VALUES(DOE.REG, id, 1, (SELECT ID FROM MatchStatus where Status = 'Not Verified'), GETDATE());
```

Error:

```
Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for **[Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

I will explain it using an example

Sample **DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   EmployeeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   EmployeeName VARCHAR(15)
)


CREATE TABLE EmployeeSalary
(
    EmployeeID INTEGER ,
    EmployeeSalary INTEGER
)
```

---

### Sample DML For Employee

```
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES(1,'SMITH')
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES(2,'ALLEN')
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES(3,'JONES')
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES(4,'MARTIN')
INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES(5,'JAMES')
```

### Sample DML For EmployeeDetails

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary
VALUES(1,23000)
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary
VALUES(2,25500)
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalary
VALUES(3,20000)
```

---

### Merge Query

```
MERGE EmployeeSalary AS stm
USING (SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeName FROM Employee) AS sd
ON stm.EmployeeID = sd.EmployeeID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stm.EmployeeSalary = stm.EmployeeSalary + 12
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(EmployeeID,EmployeeSalary)
VALUES(sd.EmployeeID,25000);
```

---

**References**

**[First Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

**[Second Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/)**

**[Third Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37172/Merge-Statement-in-SQL-Server-2008)**

**[Fourth Reference](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2007/09/20/Example-of-MERGE-in-SQL-Server-2008.aspx)**

Comment: Please see my edit... I can't figure it out my self. I have more then once the same record and I want to update all.

Comment: Refine you query more.

`On M.doeid = DOE.reg`

add more to refine the records

Comment: i MEANT, you need to add more unique columns in the join On statement to get refined matching records.